# Relation between area elements in finite deformation theory (continuum mechanics)

Tags: elasticity, continuum-mechanics

There are relations for the line and volume elements in continuum mechanics. For example:
\begin{align}
\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \  \frac{V}{V_0}&={\rm det}(F)\tag{1}\\
\lambda^2&=(F^TFe_1\cdot e_1)\tag{2}
\end{align}

with $F$ being the deformation gradient,

$$\lambda=\delta x/\delta X \tag{3}$$

is the stretch and $e_1$ is the unit vector in direction where stretch is to be found.

Is there a similar relation between infinitesimal **areas** (for ratio of deformed and undeformed areas)?

Answer (score 0):

Your first two equations can be written in other forms, so how about this?   In 1-D:

$$\lambda=\frac{L}{^0L}$$

(I use a pre-superscript for initial values and post-subscripts for spatial directions).   In 2-D:

$$\lambda_1\lambda_2=\frac{L_1}{^0L_1}\frac{L_2}{^0L_2}=\frac{A}{^0A}$$

In 3-D:

$$\lambda_1\lambda_2\lambda_3=\frac{L_1}{^0L_1}\frac{L_2}{^0L_2}\frac{L_3}{^0L_3}=\frac{V}{^0V}$$

Can't recall ever using the 2-D case but it might arise in a plane stress or plane strain calculation.

Answer (score 0):

There is, and it is usually referred to as Nanson's formula/equation.

Consider an area element with initial size $da$ and normal orientation vector $\vec{n}$ that is deformed into an area element of size $dA$ with normal orientation vector $\vec{N}$.

The relationship describing these oriented area elements before/after deformation is:

$$\vec{n}\ da = (\det{\pmb{F}})(\pmb{F}^{-T}\cdot \vec{N})dA$$

where $\pmb{F}$ is the deformation gradient tensor. See A.J.M. Spencer's [book](http://store.doverpublications.com/0486435946.html) on continuum mechanics or this [page](https://en.wikiversity.org/wiki/Continuum_mechanics/Volume_change_and_area_change) for a derivation of it.